# multi thread (for controller not server ) mvc asp.net C# razor 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

The server can be using multi thread but when one person using the website, the server will allocate one thread for one.

```
public ActionResult DownLoad(){
// do somethings
return File ( ... );
}

public ActionResult UpLoad(){
// do somethings
return View ( ... );
}
```

And when Download action is running, the person want to using some action such us Download other file, upload file ...

Why using multithread for controller ( core ) in asp.net C# razor.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Each call to the server creates a new thread

Comment: Explain your problem